# Installing ECB for Aquamacs on OSX Mavericks

Tags: macos, emacs, osx-mavericks, aquamacs, emacs-ecb

I am a complete novice at both OSX and Emacs, so unsurprisingly I'm struggling to install ECB on Aquamacs.

I followed the instructions given at https://docwhat.org/aquamacs-2-3a-and-marmalade/ using Aquamacs 3.0, but when installing the ecb-snapshot package I get the following errors:

```
ecb-semantic-wrapper.el:41:1:Error: Cannot open load file: 
no such file or directory, semantic-ctxt

jn-file-tree.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory,
jn-tree-node

jn-tree-node.el:32:1:Error: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory,
jn-utils

jn-tree-view.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory,
jn-window

jn-window.el:44:25:Error: Invalid lambda variable 
(parent jn-window-container)

test.el:31:1:Error: Cannot open load file: no such file or directory,
jn-tree-view
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shall better rely on el-get to install it.

Here is my personnal config to make it works:

```
;; =========== EL-Get =============
;; See https://github.com/dimitri/el-get
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/vendor/el-get")

(unless (require 'el-get nil 'noerror)
  (with-current-buffer
      (url-retrieve-synchronously
       "https://raw.github.com/dimitri/el-get/master/el-get-install.el")
    (let (el-get-master-branch)
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (eval-print-last-sexp))))
(require 'el-get)
(require 'el-get-status)
(setq el-get-byte-compile nil)
;; Load the local recipes
(add-to-list 'el-get-recipe-path "~/.emacs.d/el-get/recipes")

;; (setq el-get-sources '(cedet
;;                       ))
(setq el-get-sources
          '((:name ecb
                   :type git
                   :url "https://github.com/alexott/ecb.git"
                   :load "ecb.el"
                   :compile ("ecb.el"))
            ))
    (setq my-packages
          (append '(el-get)
                  (mapcar 'el-get-source-name el-get-sources))) 
(el-get 'sync my-packages)
```

Comment: This would appear to work. I've checked it briefly but in all honesty I gave up on Emacs and started using Eclipse.